# Finding element in html from js for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to write a tiny chrome extension which removes elements from webpage. i have done first task for one element correctly and successfully but i have a problem with the second one.

manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "BTU Classroom Profile Remover",
"version" : "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["https://MyRandomSite.random.ge/*"],
        "js" : ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
}
```

Content.js

```
  var element = document.querySelector('div.user-avatar');
  element.parentElement.removeChild(element); // This works

  var secondElement = document.querySelector("div.user-avatar-image"); // returned value is null
  secondElement.parentElement.removeChild(secondElement); // This causes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null"
```

But, the code for the first element is right and i have no crashes or problems with that. Also, the Path of the element is also correct because i am copying the element path from google chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Without seeing the page I can only guess. 1) If the second element is inside the first one then the observed behavior is correct. 2) The second element may be added dynamically by the site after some event like hovering the user avatar.

Comment: Maybe you could switch to `"css"` instead of `"js"` and simply hide the elements using their selectors e.g. div.user-avatar-image { display: none !important }

Comment: no, the element is existing on web page and doesnt require any hover or event. but the second idea of yours is good and i will try that out, thanks.

But, i dont get why the first block of the code (about first element) is working and the second isnt. i also checked the document state to be loaded and ready but the error is still in action. Thanks